# Where do I find a guide to show me proper syntax for SQL written for c-treeACE-ODBC_Driver

Tags: sql

I am using c-treeACE-ODBC_Driver to access a database. I have a single SQL statement to pull some data. It does not pull everything I need so I need to modify that SQL. This SQL is very different than SQL that I am accustomed to writing, in fact it is so different that I barely recognize it as SQL. Where would I find documentation that would provide a guide to this type SQL? Here is the SQL that I have:

```
SELECT "jlinmate"."num", "jlbook"."agency", "jlinmate"."curbook", "jlbook"."intdate", "jlbook"."reldate", "jlinmate"."namenum", "nmmain"."last", "nmmain"."suffix", "nmmain"."first", "nmmain"."middle", "nmmain"."race", "nmmain"."sex", "nmmain"."birthd", "nmmain"."street", "nmmain"."city", "nmmain"."state", "nmmain"."zip", "nmmain"."stateid", "jlinmate"."curloc", "nmlocal"."type", "nmlocal"."localid", "jlinmate"."seclass"
FROM "jlbook"
INNER JOIN "jlinmate" on "jlbook"."num" = "jlinmate"."curbook"
INNER JOIN "nmmain" on "jlinmate"."namenum" = "nmmain"."number"
INNER JOIN "jlbktype" on "jlbook"."type" = "jlbktype"."code"
INNER JOIN "jllocatn" on "jlinmate"."curloc" = "jllocatn"."num"
LEFT JOIN "nmlocal" on "nmmain"."number" = "nmlocal"."number"
WHERE "jlbook"."reldate" is null
ORDER BY "jlinmate"."num"
```

OK, Jarlh answered that this is ANSI/ISO SQL syntax. I understand that so why, when I add a join to a table that I know exists and I know the fields that I name in the SQL exist, would it crash? When I say crash I mean I get an error from ODBC 'Table/View/Synonym images not found'. Here is the join I added:

`INNER JOIN "images" on "nmmain"."number" = "images"."parnum"`

Thanks, John

Comment: That's ANSI/ISO SQL syntax, nothing odd at all.

Comment: Jarlh, Thank You. I modified/edited my question to ask a little more detail.

Comment: What do you find different? The `INNER JOIN` syntax, or the _delimited identifiers_ (e.g. `"jlbook"`)?

Comment: As this is ANSI/ISO SQL, you'll find documentation for it not only in the documentation for your specific DBMS but in almost every SQL guide/tutorial/document you'll find on the internet. Please can you tag your question with the DBMS you are actually connecting to (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql, etc)

Comment: Depending on dbms, table and column names _can_ be case sensitive. Try `select * from "images"`, and `select * from IMAGES` etc.

Comment: Nick, I have no idea whether it is (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql, etc). I assume that is something I would have to ask the vendor? The Data Disctionary they provided does not say.